# Use multiple line in Elvis operator in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have this code in Android Studio:

```
    val newUser = !intent.hasExtra("newUser")
    val userData = intent.getParcelableExtra("newUser") ?: UserData()
```

There is a problem in this code. if an extra that isn't `UserData` exists in intent and if its key is "newUser", `newUser` becomes `false` but `userData` becomes a new instance of `UserData`.
I am looking for something like this:

```
val userData = intent.getParcelableExtra("newUser") ?: {
    newUser = true
    UserData()
}
```

I konw this code doesn't work but is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can wrap the block in the `run` function:

```
val userData = intent.getParcelableExtra("newUser") ?: run {
    newUser = true
    UserData() 
}
```